Should we discuss common site rules on this local meta site?
Josh asked the following question on meta:
What is the proper way to deal with questions that are off-topic?
This is a general topic which is practically the same across the entire network. Is there a need to rephrase these questions on this meta site?

I did this for two specific reasons:

I felt this particular question is an important one and is worth duplicating
Ideally we will have users of this site who are not familiar with the Stack Exchange network, or how we do things here. While the content is available over at Meta Stack Overflow, that can be a... confusing and unruly site for a newcomer to our particular form of Q&A. Having important FAQ entries like "what do I do when a question is off topic" will help  our users who may be first-time Stack Exchange users. Closing off-topic questions is so important to a healthy beta that  felt it was okay to have a FAQ question here on our child meta.
The answer to that question changes until we leave beta
Because we are a brand new site we have no migration paths yet. As we gain moderators and the beta progresses, migration paths will be defined based on the site's needs. Because the process for migrating questions will be changing, I thought it was important to help users understand what the current best practices are.

Specifically, in one question a user cross-posted their question when told by the community it was off-topic, when the proper behavior would have been flagging and asking for migration. Seeing this in practice made me think a meta faq question would be helpful.
I am trying to help the site; if the community feels this is not helpful, please let me know via downvotes!

I feel there is no reason to duplicate general rules which we inherit from the network. Only when those rules would deviate from default rules it would be worth discussing them here.
Perhaps it might be nice to compose one post containing all the 'inherited' rules, with links linking to them on MSO.

Don't forget that you will eventually start attracting users who may not be familiar with the rest of the network. It never hurts to bring up issues that affect your site on the local meta.
